# « Si ce n’était pas de ma fatigue » ou « Si ce n’était pas la fatigue »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, constructions, reformulation

Si ce n’était pas de ma fatigue, je serais passé te voir.

Si ce n’était pas la fatigue, je serais passé te voir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La première phrase n'est pas du tout idiomatique, la deuxième est possible mais plutôt sans le "pas" (Si ce n'était la fatigue [qui m'en a empêché],...)

Sinon :

> Si je n'avais pas été fatigué, je serais passé te voir.
> Si la fatigue ne m'en avait pas empêché, je serais passé te voir.